# python: what is the purpose of using ( ) in python imports?

Tags: python

I just saw the following

```
from flask_login import (LoginManager, login_required, login_user, 
                         current_user, logout_user, UserMixin)
```

in [here](http://blog.thecircuitnerd.com/flask-login-tokens/)

What is the purpose of using parenthesis `()` in import statement?

Why shall someone use parenthesis while we can live without it?

is it recommended?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So the statement can wrap onto the next line.

See sections: [2.1.5.  Explicit line joining and 2.1.6. Implicit line joining](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining).

Answer (score 7):

The parentheses allow the import to span multiple lines.  Without the parentheses, you would get a syntax error.

If the imports are all on one line, the parentheses don't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to give you similar kind of example in my experience:

we can do:

```
  a, b, c = (1 ,2 ,3)
```

But suppose a line in your code is long, and you wants to break code in multiple lines:

```
  a,
  b,
  c = (1, 2, 3)
```

But you can't do like this without parenthesis on LHS, it will give you error `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`  (edit: you could do using `\` Explicit line joining on each line)

you can do it like:

```
   (a,
    b,
    c )= (1, 2, 3)
```

Instead of `\` I prefers `()` method.

May be I not answers exactly to your question, but Just I felt that I should share with you.